# Why am I getting a bad address error when trying to use sendto() on my UDP server?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp

I am quite new to socket programming. I am programming a UDP server to follow the Time protocol. I am confused since I have done a UDP server which uses the Daytime protocol and this was successful. I only copied the code of that one and just changed the message.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <time.h>
#define PORT "6000"    // the port users will be connecting to
#define MAXBUFLEN 512

// get sockaddr, Ipv4 or Ipv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }
    
    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(void)
{
    int sockfd;
    struct addrinfo info, *udpServerInfo, *connection;
    int rv;
    int nrBytes;
    const struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
    char buf[MAXBUFLEN];
    socklen_t addr_len;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    
    time_t mytime;
    mytime = time(NULL);
    
    memset(&info, 0, sizeof info);
    info.ai_family = AF_INET; // Ipv4 address
    info.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    info.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my Ip
    
    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &info, &udpServerInfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }
    
    // loop through all the results and bind to the first we can
    for(connection = udpServerInfo; connection != NULL; connection = connection->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(connection->ai_family, connection->ai_socktype,
                             connection->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("listener: socket");
            continue;
        }
        
        if (bind(sockfd, connection->ai_addr, connection->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("listener: bind");
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    
    if (connection == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "listener: failed to bind socket\n");
        return 2;
    }
    
    // printf(asctime(&mytime));
    
    freeaddrinfo(udpServerInfo);
    
    printf("listener: waiting to recvfrom...\n");
    
    addr_len = sizeof their_addr;
  
    int done = 1;
    while (done == 1 ) {
        nrBytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, MAXBUFLEN-1 , 0,
                           (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_len);
        
        
        printf("listener: got packet from %s\n",
               inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
                         get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),
                         s, sizeof s));
        
        printf("listener: packet is %d bytes long\n", nrBytes);
        buf[nrBytes] = '\0';
        printf("listener: packet contains \"%s\"\n", buf);
       
        if(sendto(sockfd, mytime, sizeof(mytime), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, addr_len) == -1) {
            perror("send %s\n");
        }
        else {
            printf ("Seconds %lu\n", mytime);
            done = 0;
        }
    }
    
    close(sockfd);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dom! :D @DomainsFeatured

Comment: Unrelated to your issue: `time_t` most likely is signed. So this `printf ("Seconds %lu\n", mytime);` should be `printf ("Seconds %ld\n", mytime);`

Comment: Also `recvfrom()` returns `ssize_t`, so this `int nrBytes;` should be `ssize_t nrBytes`. And this `printf("listener: packet is %d bytes long\n", nrBytes);` should be `printf("listener: packet is %zd bytes long\n", nrBytes);`

Comment: This `perror("send %s\n");` isn't a `printf()`! So just do `perror("sendto() failed");` or alike ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of sendto() requires a pointer. You should call it like:
sendto(sockfd, &mytime, sizeof(mytime))

Answer (score 0):

[`sendto()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sendto.3p.html) expects a pointer to the data to be sent as 2nd parameter.

So this

```
if (sendto(sockfd, mytime, ...
```

ought to be

```
if (sendto(sockfd, &mytime, ...
```

As it stands, the value of `mytime` will be taken as address, which is mostly likely an invalid one, which in turn provokes undefined behaviour inside `sendto()` when being de-referenced.

The compiler should have warned you about this.